# how to retrieve same empid have multiple deptnos with latest date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get same empid and name have different deptno values (more than one deptnos) ,again 
if we found more than one deptno then consider latest entrydate in SQL Server?
example:

```
empid   |name   |deptno |entrydate  |deptname
6       |x      |90     |2018-01-29 |PM
6       |x      |80     |2018-01-29 |lead
6       |x      |150    |2018-02-09 |tech
6       |y      |170    |2015-03-09 |jn
6       |y      |110    |2017-12-01 |Tester
6       |y      |120    |2017-12-01 |analyst
6       |z      |130    |2016-10-08 |support
```

Here empid:6 and name: x and entrydate: 2018-01-29  have multiple deptnos but we donot need this record because latest entry date is : 2018-02-09 for same empidandname
another one : empid:6 and name: y and entrydate : 2017-12-01 have multiple deptnos .this recrods we need because entry date is latest one is 2017-12-01 for thie id and name.
another one: empid:6 and name: z and entrydate: 2016-10-08 have donot have multiple deptnos then no need to show output.

```
Table : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empcnt](
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [deptno] [int] NULL,
    [entrydate] [date] NULL,
    [deptname] [varchar](50) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (1, N'a', 10, CAST(N'2016-12-24' AS Date), N'HR')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (1, N'b', 20, CAST(N'2017-10-29' AS Date), N'HR')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (3, N'd', 40, CAST(N'2015-10-10' AS Date), N'IT')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (3, N'd', 40, CAST(N'2015-10-10' AS Date), N'IT')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (4, N'e', 59, CAST(N'2016-12-17' AS Date), N'Finance')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (3, N'u', 40, CAST(N'2016-12-15' AS Date), N'CE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (5, N'h', 60, CAST(N'2017-12-27' AS Date), N'Sales')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (1, N'a', 10, CAST(N'2016-12-24' AS Date), N'HR')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (1, N'b', 50, CAST(N'2017-10-29' AS Date), N'Manager')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'x', 90, CAST(N'2018-01-29' AS Date), N'PM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'x', 80, CAST(N'2018-01-29' AS Date), N'lead')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'y', 110, CAST(N'2017-12-01' AS Date), N'Tester')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'y', 120, CAST(N'2017-12-01' AS Date), N'analyst')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'z', 130, CAST(N'2016-10-08' AS Date), N'support')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'x', 150, CAST(N'2018-02-09' AS Date), N'tech')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno], [entrydate], [deptname]) VALUES (6, N'y', 170, CAST(N'2015-03-09' AS Date), N'jn')
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below:

```
empid   |name   |deptno |entrydate  |deptname
1       |b      |50     |2017-10-29 |Manager
1       |b      |20     |2017-10-29 |HR
6       |y      |110    |2017-12-01 |Tester
6       |y      |120    |2017-12-01 |analyst
```

I tried like below :

```
SELECT *
FROM empcnt a
WHERE EXISTS
  (
    select  empid,name  
    from empcnt b
    WHERE a.empid = b.empid AND a.name = b.Name and a.entrydate=b.entrydate and 
    group by empid,name ,entrydate
    having count(distinct deptno)>1
  )
```

but above query not given expected result.
please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) and [**`count() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) and a `distinct` subquery:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      c = count(empid) over (partition by empid, name, entrydate)
    , dr = dense_rank() over (partition by empid, name order by entrydate desc)
    , *
  from (select distinct * from empcnt) x
)
select empid, name, deptno, entrydate, deptname
from cte
where c > 1 
  and dr = 1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LTN71730

returns:

```
+-------+------+--------+------------+----------+
| empid | name | deptno | entrydate  | deptname |
+-------+------+--------+------------+----------+
|     1 | b    |     20 | 2017-10-29 | HR       |
|     1 | b    |     50 | 2017-10-29 | Manager  |
|     6 | y    |    110 | 2017-12-01 | Tester   |
|     6 | y    |    120 | 2017-12-01 | analyst  |
+-------+------+--------+------------+----------+
```

---

Another way using `exists()` and `not exists()`

```
select * 
from empcnt o
where exists (
  select 1 
  from empcnt i 
  where i.empid = o.empid 
    and i.name=o.name 
    and i.entrydate=o.entrydate 
    and i.deptno<>o.deptno
  )
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from empcnt i 
    where i.empid=o.empid 
      and i.name=o.name 
      and i.entrydate>o.entrydate
  )
```